# PICOWH memory OSerror by Firebase and LCD

Tags: firebase, memory-leaks, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, lcd

```
from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM
import framebuf
import time
import os
import gc
##################### FIREBASE ########################
import network
import urequests

BL = 13
DC = 8
RST = 12
MOSI = 11
SCK = 10
CS = 9

'2inch frames'
class LCD_2inch(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 300 #actual size was 320, but decreased since of memory
        self.height = 220 #actual size of 240, but decreased since of memory
        
        self.cs = Pin(CS,Pin.OUT)
        self.rst = Pin(RST,Pin.OUT)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000_00,polarity=0, phase=0,sck=Pin(SCK),mosi=Pin(MOSI),miso=None)
        self.dc = Pin(DC,Pin.OUT)
        self.dc(1)
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.height * self.width*2)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.RGB565)
        self.init_display()
        
        self.RED   =   0x07E0
        self.GREEN =   0x001F
        self.BLUE  =   0xF800
        self.WHITE =   0xffff
        self.BLACK =   0x0000
//after several def(unimportant codes)

if __name__=='__main__':
        

    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)

    # connecting to wifi
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        wlan.connect("KT_GiGA_89C2", "9bc27xf161") # wifi_data
        print("Waiting for Wi-Fi connection", end="...")
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print(wlan.ifconfig())
        print("WiFi is Connected")

    print("Wifi is connected")

    # URL for Firebase
    url = "https://embeded-system-e8163-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"

    initial_string = "0"
    # updating initial state
    initial_state = {'phone': initial_string}
    urequests.patch(url+"/embeded_system.json", json = initial_state).json()

    phone_number = "0"
    
# first string     
    response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system.json").json()
    while (response["phone"] == phone_number):
        response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system.json").json()
        print("Waiting for the update of phone number...")
    phone_number = response['phone']
    print(f"Updated phone number to {phone_number}")
    pwm = PWM(Pin(BL))
    pwm.freq(1000)
    pwm.duty_u16(32768)#max 65535
    LCD = LCD_2inch()
    #color BRG
    LCD.fill(LCD.WHITE)

    
    
    while(1):
        if wlan.isconnected(): # phone number update only the data has changed
            response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system.json").json()
            if (phone_number != response['phone']): 
                phone_number = response['phone']
        
        for i, number in enumerate(phone_number):
            x = (i % 6) * (50)+5  
            y = (i // 6) * (90 + 20)+10  
            LCD.draw_number(number, x, y, LCD.BLACK)
        
        '''for i in range(len(phone_number)): #for the lens(unimportant)
            number = phone_number[-(i + 1)]
            x = (i % 6) * 50 + 5
            y = ((1 if i < 6 else 0)) * (90 + 20) + 10
            LCD.draw_number(number, x, y, LCD.BLACK)'''
        LCD.show()
        LCD.rst()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm now handling simple Picowh project, receives string data(ints) from Firebase, and write out them in LCD panel. Since picowh doesn't have enough RAM, so I reduced size of height to decrease buffer size.

It still receives

```
OSError: [Errno 12] ENOME
```

at the line "response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system.json").json()"
I tried sort of gc.collect() or response.close() , but I'm not so good at Micropython, so it doesn't work well.. What should I do??

Comment: Which specific line does the error get thrown? Is it the one below `# first string`, the one in the polling loop, or the one in the final loop? It is currently ambiguous because multiple lines match the one you provided. Additionally, your code only ever seems to use `phone` from your data structure. If that is the case, why not poll `url+"/embeded_system/phone.json"` instead of the whole `embeded_system` tree? Does your polling loop (the one under `# first string`) need to spam requests as it is?

Comment: There are alternative libraries available that may also solve the issues related to memory: `urllib.urequest` (allows streaming data) and `uurequests` (an old version of `urequests` without some niceties of the new version for efficiency).

Comment: in that code, `#first string` part occurs the error, and if I decrease the buffer amount, it receives requests 2~3 times in the loop, and it runs out.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll check on urllib and uurequests function.